# How can I remove elementary-tweaks?

Tags: release-freya, package-management

I installed Tweaks from [here](https://github.com/I-hate-farms/elementary-tweaks), by method described in the README.md.

```
curl -sL  http://i-hate-farms.github.io/spores/install | sudo bash - 
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

Now I want to delete it, but I can not do it correctly.

```
maxim@ProBook:~$ sudo apt-get remove elementary-tweaks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  elementary-tweaks
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1,263 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 159565 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing elementary-tweaks (1.0.1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.42.2-0ubuntu1~14.04~ricotz0) ...
sh: 1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/switchboard/personal/tweaks/theme-patcher: not found
E: Problem executing scripts DPkg::Post-Invoke '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/switchboard/personal/tweaks/theme-patcher'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
maxim@ProBook:~$
```

Now at work with other packages this error haunts me:

```
sh: 1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/switchboard/personal/tweaks/theme-patcher: not found
E: Problem executing scripts DPkg::Post-Invoke '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/switchboard/personal/tweaks/theme-patcher'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Answer (score 2):

Reinstalling `libglib2.0-0` will fix this error in my case.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove a package use ubuntu software center or

```
sudo apt-get autoremove elementary-tweaks
```

To reinstall :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall elementary-tweaks
```

Answer (score 0):

I can help you get rid of the haunting error.

Remove the line referencing `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99theme-patcher` in 
`/var/lib/dpkg/info/elementary-tweaks.list`. And then delete the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99theme-patcher` file itself.

It's probably not a perfect solution, maybe the `/var/lib/dpkg/info/elementary-tweaks.list` file should go away entirely, but I have installed a new version of elementary-tweaks and I don't want to break that one.